# Will LoRa work from Earth to the Stratosphere

Tags: radio

I'm unsure if this is the most suitable exchange however I thought it seemed most fitting personally, please correct me if I'm wrong. (I got redirected to here from the Network Engineering Exchange).

I was wondering if LoRa would work to transmit GPS data from my High Altitude Balloon back to my gateway.

From what I understand it's perfect for line of sight, which means in the sky there is nothing blocking the RF signal, however I'm not sure if there is anything else that'd cause it not to work.

Can anyone confirm if LoRa would be fine to transmit GPS position so I can locate my payload as it rises and falls?

Comment: How high is high altitude? For military reasons, it's impossible to buy commercial GPS receivers that would work at rocket-grade speeds or ICBM-level heights, and a high altitude balloon might fit into the latter category.

Comment: Only a guess, depends which quality balloon I guess but around 30km (98000ft).

Comment: I'm pretty sure your GPS will stop working long before reaching 30 km. Have you tested that it does not?

Comment: havent tested, as the balloon is relatively expensive for single time use (burst it so payload can parachute back to earth). Just wanted to see if anyone had any experience

Comment: There's plenty of high-altitude balloon projects documented in papers and even moreso websites. I'd recommend a large portion of literature/web research, for exactly the Balloon cost and effort reasons; see my personal profile quote on this website.

Comment: also, 30 km will be hard for LoRa, even under Line Of Sight conditions.

Comment: I've some research, and nobody seems to have used LoRa for data transmission, hence why I asked here if it was possible, try something new

Comment: as said, I don't think LoRa is the solution here, and you're up for much more severe problems other than your downlink.

Comment: Here, read this whole wiki: https://ukhas.org.uk/guides:gps_modules